# quill-image-resize-module importing error

Tags: reactjs, image-resizing, react-quill

I am using react-quill Editor in my react app, where I need to resize the image in the editor there for I am using "quill-image-resize-module" yarn package but when I import this package in the JS file, It's giving me an error "Could not find a declaration file for module 'quill-image-resize-module'. 'e:/development/React JS/stepsfrontend/node_modules/quill-image-resize-module/image-resize.min.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/quill-image-resize-module` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'quill-image-resize-module';"

import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module';

Answer (score 0):

For react quill i have used "https://github.com/xeger/quill-image" this package. Please don't use that "quill-image-resize-module" package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can easily just added new file in root of project like index.d.ts

and add
⬇️

```
declare module 'quill-image-uploader' {}
declare module 'quill-image-resize-module-react' {}
```

i hope this work for you